# KiCad SCH file issue

Tags: kicad

I am using KiCad 5.1.10 on Linux Mint. My question concerns the format of the SCH files. I do not understand why Eeschema is generating SCH files in the old format.

Here are some details. I created a new project. I entered a simple schematic using Eeschema. Then I saved the schematic to a SCH file. The SCH file heading says "Eeschema File Version 4." The contents are definitely in the old format. It is easy to tell the difference because according to the KiCad documentation the new format has a LISP-style syntax. I would like to have the new format SCH file.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue! KiCad version number and EESchema Schematic File version number are different.

EESchema File Version 4 is used since the release of KiCad 5.

Answer (score 0):

The new format (Lisp s-expression style) is generated by KiCad 5.99.

Also, the filename extension ".kicad_sch" is used for the new-format schematic files

Edit to add:

KiCad 5.99 can be installed by following the instructions in the "Nightly Development Builds" section at https://www.kicad.org/download/linux-mint/

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about 5.99 because at https://www.kicad.org/download/ it indicates the latest version is 5.1.10 from May 2021. Anyway I'll hunt for 5.99 and hopefully it will install on Linux Mint.

Comment: Be aware that 5.99 is a nightly build used for testing only. It should not be used for project design.

Comment: Thanks. I understand version 6 is on the way. So far the best way for me when it comes to drawing schematics is the following steps (1) pencil and paper for rough drawing (2) KiCad Eeschema (3) Once the schematic is final I use Latex with circuitikz to produce publishable quality. I know there are other ways but I like doing everything in Latex when it comes to publishing.